# Create new rasters by interpolating between pre and post rehabilitation digital elevation models

Tags: python, raster, geopandas

I have two rasters that cover a regional watershed. For most of the watershed, they are exactly the same, but over a small area defined by a shapefile (remediation_zones), the rasters are different. Raster1 represents how the site looks at the moment when it has a big quarry pit in it and raster2 is the DEM of how the site will look once the quarry pit has been filled in. I am trying to make seven new rasters to give a gradual progression of the filling up of the pit – these rasters would be the same everywhere except for the site area.
My code at the moment just creates weird rasters that either just stay at the original pit level or produce weird values – I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am new to this.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import rasterio
import geopandas as gpd
from rasterio.mask import mask

# Define function to load raster layers
def load_layers(path):
    with rasterio.open(path) as src:
        data = src.read(1)
        metadata = src.meta
        return data, metadata, src

# Load DEMs
current_DEM, current_DEM_meta, current_DEM_dataset = load_layers(current_DEM_pth)
smooth_DEM, smooth_DEM_meta, smooth_DEM_dataset = load_layers(smooth_DEM_path)

# Shapefile data
shapefile_path = r" Shapefiles\WA519 Boundary.shp"
remediation_zones = gpd.read_file(r'Shapefiles\GHD Rehabilitation Zones.shp')

# Read the shapefile
shape_dataframe = remediation_zones

# Masking
with rasterio.open(smooth_DEM_path) as smooth_DEM_dataset:
    masked, _ = mask(smooth_DEM_dataset, shape_dataframe.geometry, invert=True)

# Calculate linear interpolation between elevation values within the remediation zone
bottom = current_DEM.min()
top = smooth_DEM.max()
x_values = np.linspace(0, 1, num=8)  # Adjusted to range from 0 to 1
y_values = np.linspace(bottom, top, num=8)  # Linear interpolation between bottom and top

# Interpolate between elevation values of the current DEM and the smooth DEM
interpolated_rasters = []
for i in range(1, 8):
    weight = y_values[i]
    interpolated_elevation = current_DEM + weight * (smooth_DEM - current_DEM)
    # Mask areas outside the remediation zone
    interpolated_elevation = np.where(masked != -9999, interpolated_elevation, current_DEM)
    interpolated_rasters.append(interpolated_elevation)

# Save the modified arrays to files
for i, raster in enumerate(interpolated_rasters):
    out_file = os.path.join(workspace, f"modified_dem_{i}.tif")
    raster = raster.squeeze()  # Remove single-dimensional entries from the shape of the array
    with rasterio.open(out_file, "w", **current_DEM_meta) as dest:
        dest.write(raster, 1)

# Close datasets
current_DEM_dataset.close()
smooth_DEM_dataset.close()
```